# What methods can I use to improve my English writing skills?

Tags: academic-writing, learning

everyone!

I'm just an English learner now, but I intend to use English in my career. I suppose everyone knows requirements to pass one of common English tests. Also I wish I became a student of a European university where it's often necessary to have great language skills. Since that time I decided to improve my English because of some reasons I've written above I read a lot and I do grammar exercises, but now I feel like I need writing and speaking practices.

I know lots of words so it's not difficult to understand the main information from a book or article. Unfortunately, most of these words I know I can't use. When I write something, I won't remember these words.

I hope I'll find some ways to improve my writing skills which users of the forum could advise.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! This is probably too broad - we're a strict Q&A site, not a forum - but you may be interested in our sister site [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/). There are thousands of questions and answers there, and I'm sure at least some of them will be of use to you. if you have any *specific* problems, you can ask about them there.

Comment: In general, though, the best advice I can give you is to just *practice*. Write and write and write, then give your aching wrists a break, then write some more. Just like anything else, the more you practice writing English, the more you'll hone your skills.

Answer (score 1):

I heard once that a person has to come across a word seven times before they feel confident enough to use it for themselves.

I would recommend the following ways to practice English in order to expand your vocabulary:

### Read for pleasure

Whatever books you like to read normally, read those in English, whether it's Harry Potter or the Handmaid's Tale.

### Listen to Podcasts

Find podcasts in English on topics you find interesting and listen to them on a regular basis. If you're not sure what to start with, I'd recommend Radiolab and This American Life.

### Read with intent

As well as reading for pleasure, sometimes read with intent, and look up any word you come across that you're not fully confident about the meaning of.